# foreach loop inside of another foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, yii2

I have `courses` and `schools` array. I want to use schools array inside of courses array:

```
<? foreach ($courses as $course) {
    <div class="cat_row">
        <?= $course['location'] ?>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

When I use

```
<? foreach($schools as $coordinate){
    echo $coordinate->latitude;
} ?>
```

inside of the first foreach it shows in every block all coordinates, like:

```
|first|second|third|
|1 2 3|1 2 3 |1 2 3|
```

How can I make as:

```
|first|second|third|
|1    |2     |3    |
```

? Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: update your question with array also

Comment: use the `key` of course.

Comment: Please make clear what is the structure of your arrays and if they are guaranteed to have the same size. Generally it's not a good practice to iterate an array based on another array's keys.

Answer (score 0):

You should use just one foreach if number of items in both arrays are equal

```
<? foreach ($courses as $key=>$course) {
<div class="cat_row">
    <?= $course['location'] ?>
    <?= $schools[$key]->latitude ?>
</div>
<? } ?>
```